# Visual Studio 2012 crashing with Silverlight 5 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

On a fresh installed new computer, Visual Studio is crashing when I open some solutions which have a Silverlight 5 project using WCF Ria Services. However it works on another computer.

If I rename the folder containing the Web project (not the Silverlight one) **before** opening the solution, the solution opens well (with the web project unloaded). I then rename back the folder of the web project and manually reload it. Then Visual Studio works (build, run, debug, etc) a few time and crashes again.

If I try to debug VS as Windows asks me, I have the following exception :

```
System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233078
  Message=[Resource lookup failed - infinite recursion or critical failure detected.]
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       à System.Security.FrameSecurityDescriptor.CheckDemand2(CodeAccessPermission demand, PermissionToken permToken, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Boolean fDeclarative)
       à System.Security.SecurityRuntime.FrameDescHelper(FrameSecurityDescriptor secDesc, IPermission demandIn, PermissionToken permToken, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh)
       à System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.DemandPermission(IntPtr pNMD)
       à Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, CbtHookAction code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       à Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Shell.Controls.FocusTracker.CbtWindowsHookProc(CbtHookAction code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

I've tryied many things, as uninstall/reinstall VS, delete SUO or other files, run VS as admin, etc.
My OS is Windows 8 x64 french.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of research, problem solved :

- I installed VS 2102 **EN** (**english**) on a Windows 8 x64 **French**, because I always use VS in english, not french. That was the problem.
- I **uninstalled** VS (no need to uninstall dependencies) and reinstalled it from a **french** ISO.
- Problem solved.